# TensorFlow from sources problems

Tags: linux, tensorflow

I'm on a Fedora 26 distro

- kernel: `4.12.5`
- gcc: `5.4` (5.3.1 is what is recommended, but I couldn't find it @ gnu's)
- bazel: `0.5.3`  (`which bazel` outputs `/usr/local/bin/bazel`)
- PATH: `....:/usr/local/bin:.....`
- CUDA 8.0

I git cloned from TensorFlow's repository, ran `./configure` with the following (Kept only the essntials):

```
lease specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: /usr
Please specify the location where cuDNN 5 library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr]:/usr/local/cudnn
Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /usr/bin/gcc]: /home/elior/gcc54/bin/gcc
```

If anything more is needed let me know and I'll post it. Configuration seems to be finished by now and when I run

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

I get the following error

> ......
>   Cuda Configuration Error: Repository command failed
>   find: ‘/usr/nvvm’: No such file or directory

Now few things that could have gone wrong that I could think of.

1. Using `which nvcc` outputs `/usr/bin/nvcc` but when the configuration asks me for the path for the CUDA compiler and I reply `/usr/bin/nvcc` it says that `/usr/bin/nvcc/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0` could not be found, so I did a search and I found that file at `/usr/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0` so that's why I've put the path as `/usr`
2. Pretty much the same thing with cudNN, I downloaded 5.1 from the site, and I've extracted it into `/usr/local/cudnn` but when I put in cudNN version I want to use as 5.1 it can't find `/usr/local/cudnn/libcudnn.so.5.1` but I do have there a 5.0, so I just say "5" as the version and it works out

That's all I could come up by now... But I really want to get this installation done, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]: /usr

here you need to se the path to cuda installation directory; which is 
`/usr/local/cuda` (as it's also the default); Now you set it as `/usr` which is wrong; either you leave it as default or set it as `/usr/local/cuda`

> Please specify the location where cuDNN 5 library is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr]:/usr/local/cudnn

here also the usual path that you need to set is `/usr/local/cuda/`

> cudnn install

```
cp cudnn/lib64/cudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
cp cudnn/include/* /usr/local/cuda/include
```

Comment: I don't even have a `/usr/local/cuda/` dir only a `/usr/local/cudnn` one.
When I set it to different directories than the ones I supplied, I get errors that it can't find certain files like `libcudart.so.8`

Comment: cuddn files should be cuda files ...lib64 and include. in this case you need copy the cuddn respective file to /parth/tocuda/lib64 and /path/to/cuda/include

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow, given the directory I've shown to work, the `/usr` and the `/usr/local/cudnn` what order should I follow to achieve the desired paths?

Comment: There are no `cudnn*` files at all

Comment: my bad! installation of cuddn should be with cuda...here you may copy ur libcuddn*.so file to /usr/lib64 and cudnn.h file to '/usr/include' –

Comment: If you will, I opened a chat room where you could help me :) 
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/152250/tensorflow-installation-gpu?tab=general

Comment: sure!lets talk over there

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a workaround - use docker

[nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Installation)

[tensorflow docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/)

Answer (score 0):

we spend way too many days/hours on this GPU stuff.  hopefully we can save you some time by sharing the following links:

AWS + Docker + CUDA + CuDNN + GPU + Spark + TensorFlow + JupyterHub

https://github.com/fluxcapacitor/pipeline/wiki/AWS-GPU-Tensorflow-Docker

Google + Docker + CUDA + CuDNN + GPU + Spark + TensorFlow + JupyterHub

https://github.com/fluxcapacitor/pipeline/wiki/GCP-GPU-TensorFlow-Docker

We use these instructions for meetups and conferences, etc.  And we update them all the time when stuff breaks - which is quite often, unfortunately, with all the moving parts involved.

The Docker image we reference is here:  https://github.com/fluxcapacitor/pipeline/blob/master/gpu.ml/Dockerfile.gpu

This Docker image extends from this: https://github.com/fluxcapacitor/pipeline/blob/master/package/gpu/cuda8/16.04/Dockerfile

which extends from this Nvidia Base Docker Image:  FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn6-devel-ubuntu16.04

This Nvidia Base Docker Image already includes the CuDNN libraries.

We have a need to build TensorFlow from source as we use a lot of TensorFlow's performance optimization utilities that must be built from source.

Hope that helps!  More details and references available at the GitHub and DockerHub repos reference here: http://pipeline.ai

Comment: That's great... Do you happen to have a docker image for a local machine? I have a GPU which I can use instead of paying for one, and docker seems like a good solution